# Is it possible for R to create a bubble chart with different dimensions?

Tags: r

I want to create a bubble chart like this:

[sample chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT6my.png)

I want the y axis for project stage, and x axis for nothing. The size of the circle could be the number of projects and the color can be the status.

I think it should be a bubble chart of point chart, so I add solid value for x axis to set x position for all circle. But I don't have an idea how to set y axis for them.

This is my data sample:

```
test<- data.frame(
    stage = c("Designment","Designment","Development","Development","Development","Go Live","Go Live","Requirement","Requirement","Test","Test","UAT","UAT"),
    status=c("At Risk","On Track","At Risk","On Hold","On Track","Completed","On Track","On Hold","On Track","Completed","On Track","Completed","On Track"),
    total=c("1","9","1","2","23","25","2","9","11","1","6","1","1"),
    x=c("1.00114754443462","1.01564186197464","0.998163923987934","1.00428226961525","1.00490918326707","0.996299554522548","0.979025253250673","0.996035528009065","0.997494036022247","0.998396639432905","0.987719363426524","0.990205701650603","1.01609094768587"),
    y=c("0.444705037188138","0.628219900896655","0.538614704467962","0.587639745611629","0.289049383370184","0.568458079545019","0.302063527274047","0.520840349575939","0.687424167003373","0.564338710368995","0.593610161950449","0.662218219412209","0.370813953512016")
)
```

Is there any solution to this kind of chart?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ggplot2` you can:

```r
library(palmerpenguins)
library(tidyverse)
penguins %>% 
  group_by(species, sex) %>% 
  summarise(
    body_mass_g = mean(body_mass_g),
    n = n(),
    .groups = "drop"
  ) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = body_mass_g, y = species, colour = sex, size = n)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), size = 3, colour = "white") +
  scale_size(range = c(15, 30), guide = NULL)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much!
I can use ggplot2 to make this chart right now, and I want to make all the circles, for example , all the Adelie circle together, one by one, even for covered, instead of one circle on one position. 
Is there any function that can help to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

There are a few different ways to create a bubble chart in R. One way is to use the "ggplot2" package. Another way is to use the "plotly" package.

Comment: Please provide a code example. Your answer is too vague and needs supporting information.